# How can I install a certificate into the local machine store programmatically using Java?

Tags: java, firefox

I am trying to install certificate into browser's store using Java/Javascript.
I was able to store it in IE, but when it comes to mozilla I am not able to install it..

any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Installing a certificate into the local machine store using Java or Javascript sounds like a security risk to me — if it is somehow possible then I would expect that to be treated as a bug and fixed. Both Java and Javascript are normally sandboxed so they wouldn't have access to modify system settings.

I suggest that you either:

- ask your users to download the certificate and manually install it, or
- if the users are in your office, write a shell script to install the certificate (see [Programmatically Install Certificate into Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435000/programmatically-install-certificate-into-mozilla))