# Script for Install SSL Certificate on Trusted Root Certificate Store

Tags: windows, batch-file, ssl-certificate

I want to install self-signed certificate for IE, Firefox and Chrome in Windows (XP and 7).

I need to install certificate for several systems, So I planed to create .bat file that install certificate for browsers. I got following command while googled

> certutil -addstore -f -enterprise -user root root_ca.cer

But it only for IE. Is there any option for Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 12):

Bit of an old post but thought I would throw in my two cents anyway. You are right, that command in a batch script will install the certificate `root_ca.cer` into the trusted CA store. I would modify the line to be:

```
certutil -addstore -f -enterprise -user root "%~dp0root_ca.cer"
```

This way the shell will expand `%~dp0` to the path of the executing script so you can run it across a network from a UNC path and it will still work.

In answer to your other question, Chrome will (as of writing this post) read from the windows certificate store so there is no need to do anything special; just restart chrome after running the script and it should be sweet.

As for Mozilla [check out this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435000/programmatically-install-certificate-into-mozilla) for a script to do that. Simples!

Comment: Is there a solution to do this through a C++ program? Could you please have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673163/import-a-certificate-using-cryptuiwizimport-automatically-as-a-trusted-root-with ?