# import a certificate using CryptUIWizImport automatically as a trusted root with C++

Tags: c++, winapi, cryptography, certificate, root-certificate

I am using the following code to import a certificate as a trusted root:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include "Cryptuiapi.h"

#pragma comment(lib, "Cryptui.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
    CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO importSrc;    
    memset(&importSrc, 0, sizeof(CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO));    
    importSrc.dwSize = sizeof(CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SRC_INFO);    
    importSrc.dwSubjectChoice = CRYPTUI_WIZ_IMPORT_SUBJECT_FILE;    
    importSrc.pwszFileName = L“C:\\PathToCert\\MyCertificate.cer”;
    importSrc.pwszPassword = L"";    
    importSrc.dwFlags = CRYPT_EXPORTABLE | CRYPT_USER_PROTECTED;             
    if (CryptUIWizImport(    
      CRYPTUI_WIZ_NO_UI,    
      NULL,    
      NULL,    
      &importSrc,    
      NULL    
    ) == 0)    
    {    
      printf(“CryptUIWizImport error 0x%x\n”, GetLastError());    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, this approach imports my certificate as a `Intermediate Certificate Authorities` while I need to import it as a `Trusted Root Certificate Authorities`. I do not want to use any wizard approach and I can not change my certificate.

Is it possible to import this certificate as a trusted root?

Is there any property in `CryptUIWizImport` to set the certificate type as the trusted root?

Thanks in advances

Answer (score 1):

We should execute a batch file command from inside the C++ code:

```
#include "stdafx.h";
#include "windows.h"
#include "Cryptuiapi.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#pragma comment(lib,"Cryptui.lib")

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    char buffer[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileNameA(NULL, buffer, MAX_PATH);
    string::size_type pos = string(buffer).find_last_of("\\/");
    string myPath = string(buffer).substr(0,pos);    
    string myCommand = "certutil -addstore -f -enterprise -user root \""+myPath+"\\IRIPO CA.cer\"";
    system(myCommand.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the `certificate` file should be put next to the `exe` file.