# How to deal with certificates using Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, browser

I am using [Selenium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_%28software%29) to launch a browser. How can I deal with the webpages (URLs) that will ask the browser to accept a certificate or not?

In Firefox, I may have a website like that asks me to accept its certificate like this:

[image: Firefox]

On the Internet Explorer browser, I may get something like this:

[image]

On Google Chrome:

[image: Google Chrome]

I repeat my question: **How can I automate the acceptance of a website's certificate when I launch a browser (Internet Explorer, Firefox and Google Chrome) with Selenium (Python programming language)**?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

For the Firefox, you need to set `accept_untrusted_certs` `FirefoxProfile()` option to `True`:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.accept_untrusted_certs = True

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get('https://cacert.org/')

driver.close()
```

For Chrome, you need to add [`--ignore-certificate-errors`](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#ignore-certificate-errors) `ChromeOptions()` argument:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://cacert.org/')

driver.close()
```

For the Internet Explorer, you need to set [`acceptSslCerts`](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#IE_specific) desired capability:

```
from selenium import webdriver

capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().INTERNETEXPLORER
capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True

driver = webdriver.Ie(capabilities=capabilities)
driver.get('https://cacert.org/')

driver.close()
```

---

Actually, according to the [`Desired Capabilities` documentation](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities), setting `acceptSslCerts` capability to `True` should work for all browsers since it is a generic read/write capability:

> acceptSslCerts
>
> boolean
>
> Whether the session should accept all SSL certs
>   by default.

---

Working demo for Firefox:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
```

Setting `acceptSslCerts` to `False`:

```
>>> capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
>>> capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = False
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)
>>> driver.get('https://cacert.org/')
>>> print(driver.title)
Untrusted Connection
>>> driver.close()
```

Setting `acceptSslCerts` to `True`:

```
>>> capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
>>> capabilities['acceptSslCerts'] = True
>>> driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=capabilities)
>>> driver.get('https://cacert.org/')
>>> print(driver.title)
Welcome to CAcert.org
>>> driver.close()
```

Comment: I'm not being able to make it work on IE 11, it just keeps showing me the Certificate Error page

Comment: For firefox 48+ using geckodriver still have issue ,this's open issue in geckodriver ,they still have no idea for it ,see the [Bug Issue](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/93)

Comment: This answer is no longer valid, use 'acceptInsecureCerts' instead

Comment: This comment might be very late but helpful for people reaching the question now. I tried all of the above and nothing worked. Only managed to pass the Error with:
`driver.get("javascript:document.getElementById('overridelink').click()")`

Comment: for chromedriver I ended up passing all of these four strings to options.add_argument --> `allow-running-insecure-content` and `ignore-certificate-errors` and `allow-insecure-localhost` and `unsafely-treat-insecure-origin-as-secure` (you can try to find more by: `strings /opt/google/chrome/chrome | grep insecure` and similar grepping)

Comment: For me, firefox still showed the warning later on a page redirect/form submission, not at the beginning. Chrome worked fine.

Answer (score 10):

For Firefox:

```
ProfilesIni profile = new ProfilesIni();
FirefoxProfile myprofile = profile.getProfile("default");
myprofile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
myprofile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(myprofile);
```

For **Chrome** we can use:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--ignore-certificate-errors"));
driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

For **Internet Explorer** we can use:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);      
Webdriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Comment: The question was about Python. You could at least write what language is that.

Comment: Be careful, 'ProfilesIni' is deprecated !

Comment: Hope that java version may help   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
  options .addArguments("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes", "--ignore-certificate-errors");
  
  ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);

Answer (score 7):

For Firefox Python:

The Firefox Self-signed certificate bug has now been fixed:
[accept ssl cert with marionette firefox webdrive python splinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37868425/accept-ssl-cert-with-marionette-firefox-webdrive-python-splinter/41711649#41711649)

"acceptSslCerts" should be replaced by "acceptInsecureCerts"

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
ff_binary = FirefoxBinary("path to the Nightly binary")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=ff_binary, capabilities=caps)
driver.get("https://expired.badssl.com")
```

Comment: And now Firefox 52 is live.  
Upgrade **Firefox**, upgrade **selenium** to v3.3, download **geckodriver** to v0.15 and you don't even need the binary path anymore!

Answer (score 6):

For people coming to this question related to headless chrome via python selenium, you may find https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739#c102 to be useful.

It looks like you can either do

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--allow-insecure-localhost')
```

or something along the lines of the following (may need to adapt for python):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions()
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome()
caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options)
caps.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts", true)
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(caps)
```

Answer (score 6):

And in C# (.net core) using `Selenium.Webdriver` and `Selenium.Chrome.Webdriver` like this:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("--ignore-certificate-errors");
using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location),options))
{ 
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions().addArguments("--proxy-server=http://" + proxy);
options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion

Answer (score 2):

Javascript:

```
const capabilities = webdriver.Capabilities.phantomjs();
capabilities.set(webdriver.Capability.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
capabilities.set(webdriver.Capability.SECURE_SSL, false);
capabilities.set('phantomjs.cli.args', ['--web-security=no', '--ssl-protocol=any', '--ignore-ssl-errors=yes']);
const driver = new webdriver.Builder().withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome(), capabilities).build();
```

Answer (score 2):

In selenium python, you need to set `desired_capabilities` as:

```
desired_capabilities = {
    "acceptInsecureCerts": True
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue with Selenium and Behat. If you want to pass the parameters via `behat.yml`, here is what it needs to look like:

```
default:
    extensions:
        Behat\MinkExtension:
            base_url: https://my-app.com
            default_session: selenium2
            selenium2:
                browser: firefox
                capabilities:
                    extra_capabilities:
                        acceptInsecureCerts: true
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating a profile and then a driver helps us get around the certificate issue in Firefox:

```
var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.SetPreference("network.automatic-ntlm-auth.trusted-uris","DESIREDURL");
driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Comment: what about Internet Explorer and Google Chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

For those who come to this issue using **Firefox** and the above solutions don't work, you may try the code below (my original answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53605370/7563824)).

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']['marionette.contentListener'] = True
profile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']['network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist'] = False
profile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']['security.cert_pinning.enforcement_level'] = 0
profile.set_preference('webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer', False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", temp_folder)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                   "text/plain, image/png")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--ignore-certificate-errors");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

I have used it for Java with Chrome browser it is working nice

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all but the necessary certificate from your browser's certificate store and then configure the browser to automatically select the certificate when only one certificate is present.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update regarding this issue.

**Require Drivers:**

`Linux: Centos 7 64bit, Window 7 64bit`

`Firefox: 52.0.3`

`Selenium Webdriver: 3.4.0 (Windows), 3.8.1 (Linux Centos)`

`GeckoDriver: v0.16.0 (Windows), v0.17.0 (Linux Centos)`

Code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/home/seleniumproject/geckodrivers/linux/v0.17/geckodriver");

ProfilesIni ini = new ProfilesIni();


// Change the profile name to your own. The profile name can 
// be found under .mozilla folder ~/.mozilla/firefox/profile. 
// See you profile.ini for the default profile name

FirefoxProfile profile = ini.getProfile("default"); 

DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
cap.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);

FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();

GeckoDriverService service =new GeckoDriverService.Builder(firefoxBinary)
    .usingDriverExecutable(new 
File("/home/seleniumproject/geckodrivers/linux/v0.17/geckodriver"))
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .usingAnyFreePort()
    .build();
try {
    service.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions().setBinary(firefoxBinary).setProfile(profile).addCapabilities(cap);

driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");

System.out.println("Life Title -> " + driver.getTitle());
driver.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this on .net c# with PhantomJSDriver with selenium web driver 3.1

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void headless()
    {


        var driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\Driver\phantomjs\");
        driverService.SuppressInitialDiagnosticInformation = true;
        driverService.AddArgument("--web-security=no");
        driverService.AddArgument("--ignore-ssl-errors=yes");
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver(driverService);

        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("XXXXXX.aspx");

        Thread.Sleep(6000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I run into this issue with newer browsers, I just use AppRobotic Personal edition to click specific screen coordinates, or tab through the buttons and click.

Basically it's just using its macro functionality, but won't work on headless setups though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. However when I tried opening the website manually in the browser the certificate was correct, but in the details the name was "DONOTTRUST".

The difference of certificate was caused by Fiddler that was running in background and decrypting all HTTPS content before reencrypting it.

To fix my problem, just close Fiddler on machine. If you need to keep Fiddler opened, then you can uncheck Decrypt SSL in Fiddler Settings.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET, what worked for me was the following...

```
var chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions { AcceptInsecureCertificates = true };
```

Pretty much, it tells the ChromeDriver options not to halt browser execution when an insecure certificate is detected, and to proceed as normal.

Answer (score 0):

Simple approach,

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService

# pip install webdriver-manager
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager



def get_chrome_capabilities():
    caps = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
    caps['acceptSslCerts'] = True
    caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = True
    opts = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    caps.update(opts.to_capabilities())
    return caps


# ChromeDriveManager to automate and download webdriver
service = ChromeService(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
  service=service,
  desired_capabilities=get_chrome_capabilities(),
)

# Use this instead of the above if you are already setup
# driver = webdriver.Chrome(desired_capabilities=get_chrome_capabilities())


driver.get("http://www.google.com")
assert "google" in driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score -3):

It looks like it still doesn't have a standard decision of this problem. In other words - you still can't say "Okay, do a certification, whatever if you are Internet Explorer, Mozilla or Google Chrome". But I found one post that shows how to work around the problem in Mozilla Firefox. If you are interested in it, you can check it [here](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-https-and-self-signed-certificate-exeptions/).

Comment: But what about the code above done in Java ? It is asking each browser to accept the certificate of the current visted website. Can not we do the same in Python ?