# How to write a script to accept SSL Certificates

Tags: javascript, bash, selenium, ssl-certificate

I'm testing a web application using selenium. Here, I'm writing the selenium test in Javascript. But I couldn't find a way to automate SSL certs acceptance.

Using [the profile class](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/module_selenium-webdriver_firefox_profile_class_Profile.html) I tried doing something like this:

Is there anything I’m missing?

var profile = new firefox.Profile()
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCerts(true)

var options = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile)

var firefoxDriver = new web driver.Builder()
.forBrowser(‘firefox’)
.usingServer(‘http://127.0.0.1 :4444/wd/hub’)
.setFirefoxOptions(options)
.build()

firefoxDriver.get(url)

But this doesn't seems to work. Is there any way I can write a bash script(which I can call in my test) or is there any other way in Javascript that accept SSL certs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with certificates using selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium)

Comment: how do you pass the profile to webdriver? Have you tried `profile. assumeUntrustedCertIssuer(true)`?

Comment: @danielepolencic profile.assumeUntrustedCertIssuer(true) doesn't work? Any other suggestions?

Comment: @JeffC That's not working in javascript. I'm using similar methods in javascript: Is there anything I’m missing?

var profile = new firefox.Profile()
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCerts(true)

var options = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile)

var firefoxDriver = new web driver.Builder()
.forBrowser(‘firefox’)
.usingServer(‘http://127.0.0.1 :4444/wd/hub’)
.setFirefoxOptions(options)
.build()

firefoxDriver.get(url)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?                                                                                                                                                                profile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I’m trying the following but it doesn’t work. Is there anything I’m missing?

var profile = new firefox.Profile()
profile.setAcceptUntrustedCerts(true)

var options = new firefox.Options().setProfile(profile)

var firefoxDriver = new web driver.Builder()
.forBrowser(‘firefox’)
.usingServer(‘http://127.0.0.1 :4444/wd/hub’)
.setFirefoxOptions(options)
.build()

firefoxDriver.get(url)