# How to accept a SSL certificate using selenium?

Tags: selenium, ssl, automation, popup

Thanks for your help in advance.... So I am testing an application and when I try to visit the url using chromedriver, the application prompts me to accept the SSL certificate(Security reasons). Is there a way to click ok on that prompt using selenium, or is there a way to automate that somehow? 
I know how to handle other prompt but just not able to click ok on that prompt.

Please advice... I am now wondering if this is something that can be automated or is it better for me to bypass and not get prompted for that cert...

I am trying to accept a trusted cert [Cert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et7go.png)

Comment: See similar question here: [How to stop Chrome's Select a certificate window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653785/how-to-stop-chromes-select-a-certificate-window/44455445#44455445)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `--ignore-certificate-errors` `ChromeOptions()` argument:

Look at that [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium) there is right answer for your question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I am aware of ignoring and accepting using desired capabilites but I have edited my post up and added a pic to show what cert I am trying to accept cvan you please advise... thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

**This should help. (C#)**

```
try
{
   IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
   alert.Accept();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{}
```