# how to have firefox ignore ssl?

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

Simple, using selenium `IWebDriver`, I need a way for firefox to accept every SSL, because now it's blocking a lot.

Is there something in the configuration to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with certificates using Selenium?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium)

Comment: thanks for the reply! however from what I read in the website at the end, it would be that there is a problem since a while with firefox? https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/1998

Comment: because I did this many time and it doesn't work... for ff

Comment: Are you using marionette?

Comment: thanks for your reply! good point actually I don't use it.... but the error is the same... even if I set to accept untrusted certificate true, it doesn't...