# Python Webdriver - Firefox profiles - Error code: SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER -

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, browser-automation

Read through all over the internet but still can't  resolve the following error while trying to run test script on my test environment

> "The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is
>   unknown. The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate
>   certificates. An additional root certificate may need to be imported."

All software versions are as follows:
Firefox - 60.0.2
Python - 3.6
Selenium - 3.12.0
Gecko driver - 20.1

Tried the following and failed:
1- Created custom firefox profile and tried to call in the webdriver code

```
 profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile("C:/Users/username/AppData/Roaming/Mozilla/Firefox/Profiles/p88ifbjn.Sel")
 profile.set_preference('webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer', True)
 profile.update_preferences()
 driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

2- Binary code
3 - Accepting un-trusted code
4 - Tried to manually accept certificates

Nothing worked for me, let me know if anyone can help, I am new to automation

Comment: Most of the answers provided are for Java, need guidance for Python, please help as I have wasted 3 days now searching internet, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

I search around and couldn't find an working answer either. Interestingly, I found that with updating some already discussed settings, it works in iPython console but not in terminal, for whatever reason. So I went to compare all modified configurations in **about:config**. There are three preference items that differs. Updating them actually does the magic for me in Mac OS and in Ubuntu. Here is the code. Note you must updating them by changing the default preferences. Code tested in Firefox 63.0.3 with geckodriver version 0.23.0.

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']['marionette.contentListener'] = True
profile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']['network.stricttransportsecurity.preloadlist'] = False
profile.DEFAULT_PREFERENCES['frozen']['security.cert_pinning.enforcement_level'] = 0
profile.set_preference('webdriver_assume_untrusted_issuer', False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", temp_folder)
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk",
                       "text/plain, image/png")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code block works for me :

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("security.enterprise_roots.enabled", True)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```