# Firefox Browser: Insecure Certificate- Selenium c#

Tags: c#, unit-testing, selenium, firefox

I am trying to test a website using selenium but i can't because i am getting an exception that firefox is insecure.

I am getting this

```
System.InvalidOperationException: ' (InsecureCertificate)'
```

respectively:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: but i need a c# solution

Comment: Pulled in image.

Answer (score 0):

There are two answers here:

1. The owner of `labserver`, you want to talk this person. Because they setup a server that uses bad certificates.
2. Now, if fixing the certificate isn't an option, then you have "simply" ensure that the *browser* that Selenium is using in your setup is configured so that it *ignores* that security violation.

That 2nd point has *nothing* to do with python vs java vs C#. It is about browser configuration! Therefore that suggested existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium) would be a good starting point for you!