# python selenium white page

Tags: python, selenium, cookies, web-crawler

I want get html from [here](https://www.elal.com/en/PassengersInfo/Useful-Info/Flight-Schedule/Pages/Flight-Updates.aspx). This link work OK in my browser. But if I disable cookies in settings, this page reload endless.

My basic code return blank page

```
options = Options() 
options.add_argument("--start-maximized") 

cpll = "C:\Users\aaa\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(cpll,chrome_options=options)
driver.get("https://www.elal.com/en/PassengersInfo/Useful-Info/Flight-Schedule/Pages/Flight-Updates.aspx")
```

[image]

I tried [add cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver), [ignore SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium), change driver version, but I get this page...

What could be the problem?

Comment: I Think it has to do something with where you are automating from have you tried using VPN?

Answer (score 0):

with

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.elal.com/en/PassengersInfo/Useful-Info/Flight-Schedule/Pages/Flight-Updates.aspx")
```

... i get a normal page
[image]