# Selenium tests giving SSL error when i run my tests

Tags: selenium, ssl

Selenium tests giving SSL certificate error

Selenium tests giving this error "IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate veri(...)"

IOError: [Errno socket error] [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate veri(...)

Already tried add this but does not work:

```
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with certificates using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium)

Comment: @SiKing, no i have tried it but does not work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it using this command:

```
import ssl
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
```