# Selenium not loading the page through Proxy, showing Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, burp

I am unable to load any page through Selenium if the Burp proxy is on, the code I run is the following

```
void runBrowserAutomatization(File fileDriver, String seleniumTrack, boolean isHeadless) {

        this.fileDriver = fileDriver;
        String filePath = this.fileDriver.getAbsolutePath();

        WebDriver driver;

        if (gui.usedBrowser().toLowerCase().contains("chrome")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", filePath);

            Proxy p = new Proxy();
            p.setHttpProxy(PROXY_SOCKET); // PROXY_SOCKET = "127.0.0.1:8080"
            p.setSslProxy(PROXY_SOCKET); // PROXY_SOCKET = "127.0.0.1:8080"

            ChromeOptions opt = new ChromeOptions();

            opt.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, p);

            driver = new ChromeDriver(opt);

        } else if (gui.usedBrowser().toLowerCase().contains("firefox")) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", filePath);

            Proxy p = new Proxy();
            p.setHttpProxy(PROXY_SOCKET); // PROXY_SOCKET = "127.0.0.1:8080"
            p.setSslProxy(PROXY_SOCKET); // PROXY_SOCKET = "127.0.0.1:8080"


            FirefoxOptions opt = new FirefoxOptions();
            opt.setCapability(CapabilityType.PROXY, p);

            driver = new FirefoxDriver(opt);

        } else {
            PrintMsg("No browser selected...");
            return;
        }


        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(TIMEOUT_SEC, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        WebElement currentElement = null;

        try {

            driver.get("https://www.ansa.it/");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            PrintMsg((e.getClass().getName()+ "\nError message: " + e.getMessage()));
            driver.quit();
        }

        driver.quit();

    }
```

The error shown in Google Chrome is the following

```
timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.001
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.97)
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.1.108', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 83.0.4103.97, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b..., userDataDir: C:\Users\Stefano\AppData\Lo...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:50862}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=127.0.0...., setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify, webauthn:virtualAuthenticators: true}
Session ID: 2bc6869c6817e3dc3cbd6cb4866acc3b
```

And the Burp cmd prints this log

```
Starting ChromeDriver 83.0.4103.39 (ccbf011cb2d2b19b506d844400483861342c20cd-refs/branch-heads/4103@{#416}) on port 42031
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
[1591285080.490][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
[1591285080.491][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.001
[1591285080.493][SEVERE]: Timed out receiving message from renderer: -0.001
```

While in Firefox the exception message is the following

```
Timeout loading page after 10000ms
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'MSI', ip: '192.168.1.108', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_251'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 76.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:buildID: 20200507114007, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.26.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 3164, moz:profile: C:\Users\Stefano\AppData\Lo..., moz:shutdownTimeout: 60000, moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, proxy: Proxy(manual, http=127.0.0...., rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 0caec7ca-d654-445c-998a-1f41f058d533
```

And the Burp cmd is showing the following log

```
1591285235902   mozrunner::runner       INFO    Running command: "C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "C:\\Users\\Stefano\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\rust_mozprofiledfeV0Z"
1591285236140   addons.webextension.doh-rollout@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'doh-rollout@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: networkStatus
1591285236367   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: mozillaAddons
1591285236367   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: telemetry
1591285236367   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: resource://pdf.js/
1591285236367   addons.webextension.screenshots@mozilla.org     WARN    Loading extension 'screenshots@mozilla.org': Reading manifest: Invalid extension permission: about:reader*
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/XULStore.jsm, line 66: Error: Can't find profile directory.
1591285237876   Marionette      INFO    Listening on port 50991
1591285237910   Marionette      WARN    TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session
1591285237912   Marionette      INFO    Proxy settings initialised: {"proxyType":"manual","httpProxy":"127.0.0.1:8080","sslProxy":"127.0.0.1:8080"}
JavaScript warning: https://www.ansa.it/sito/js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js, line 2: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead
JavaScript warning: https://www.ansa.it/sito/js/0130122946_js-head-pack.js, line 1: unreachable code after return statement
JavaScript error: https://optimized-by.4wnetwork.com/js/sdk.min.js, line 63: TypeError: a is undefined
JavaScript error: https://optimized-by.4wnetwork.com/js/sdk.min.js, line 63: TypeError: a is undefined
JavaScript error: https://optimized-by.4wnetwork.com/js/sdk.min.js, line 63: TypeError: a is undefined
JavaScript error: , line 0: NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
JavaScript error: , line 0: NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
JavaScript error: , line 0: NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
JavaScript error: , line 0: NotAllowedError: The play method is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
1591285252948   Marionette      INFO    Stopped listening on port 50991

###!!! [Child][RunMessage] Error: Channel closing: too late to send/recv, messages will be lost


###!!! [Child][MessageChannel::SendAndWait] Error: Channel error: cannot send/recv
```

Note that without Proxy pages are loaded with no problem

I really need help so if you have any advice, fix or workaround please answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using the HTTPS proxy causes the browser to show you an untrusted certificate warning. That causes problems with Selenium. If you set a breakpoint at `driver.quit()` or remove it, you might see what's in the browser.

You have at least two options:

- Ignore untrusted certificate errors in general - See [How to deal with certificates using Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078)
- Ignore a specific untrusted certificate by configuring and using a profile

Once that's working, you'll still have to interact with Burp Suite before Selenium times out. It's a race.

Comment: Hi, no certificate warning is shown. I commented the "quit()" line to prevent the browser to close, but a blank screen with no message is shown instead of the certificate error.