# How to skip certificate selection while opening URL

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, ssl-certificate

I have skip certificate method:

```
private void skipCertificateSelection() throws AWTException, InterruptedException {
    LOGGER.info("Timeout (5s) before closing certificate popup...");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    Robot robot = new Robot();
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
}
```

It used to work but now certificate selection pop up is displayed while executing

```
    driver.get(url);
```

so I'm not able to skip it.

How to handle skipping certificate while opening page from URL ?

Comment: You can use default browser profile to launch browser where the certificate is already selected, so it won't ask each time you open the browser.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium this answer your question?