# how to handle SSL error while using chrome webdriver in selenium python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, ssl, webdriver

selenium version : 4.16.0

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install())) driver.get(url)`

get this error :
[4236:12816:0202/051519.769:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(974)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200
[4236:12816:0202/051520.534:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(974)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -200

able to launch the chrome and url loads but hits SSL cert error by clicking advanced > proceed to .. able to access the page
but how to get it done by script

tried [this](https://testrig.medium.com/handling-ssl-certificate-errors-with-selenium-webdriver-a-technical-guide-47404e9cdd20)
[this also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24507078/how-to-deal-with-certificates-using-selenium) still not working