# How to Import a Certificate from Windows into Firefox

Tags: firefox, import, certificate, ca

I need to script the export of a cert from our Windows store into Firefox. I am having trouble getting the cert into the correct "container". The certificate, as generated from a command line as well, is a .pfx file with a password. I can manually import the cert into Firefox under the "Your Certificates" tab of the Certificate Manager. However, when I run the command line, it dumps the cert under the tab labeled "Others" and the website we're trying to access either can't find the cert there or there's a problem with the import itself.

My first couple of attempts failed with errors, but following up on them I found a site that suggested I convert the .pfx file to a .pem file. I followed those instructions and the command line now runs without error. The other thing to note here is using the GUI, I cannot import the .PEM file, but I can import the .PFX file.

Assuming that the .pem file is encoded and formatted correctly, how can I get this line of code to put the cert into the right container?

certutil -A -n "My Certificate" -d c:\temp\CertImport -t "CTu,," -u "c" -a -f pword.txt -i CertEric.pem 
(I added the '-f' argument in case its needed to import the password protected file. I've run this both with and without it and got the same results.)

I also exported the cert in a .cer format.

Here are some other attempts and results:

---

certutil -A -n "My Certificate" -d c:\temp\CertImport -t "CTu,," -u "c" -a -f pword.txt -i CertEric.pfx

certutil: could not obtain certificate from file: security library: improperly formatted DER-encoded message.

---

certutil -A -n "My Certificate" -d c:\temp\CertImport -t "CTu,," -u "c" -a -f pword.txt -i CertEric.cer

certutil: could not obtain certificate from file: security library: improperly formatted DER-encoded message. 
(Although, dropping the '-a' argument allowed this command to complete without error.)

---

certutil -A -n "My Certificate" -d c:\temp\CertImport -t "CTu,," -u "c" -f pword.txt -i CertEric.pfx

certutil: could not obtain certificate from file: security library: invalid arguments.
(This one uses the .pfx file and drops the '-a' argument)

---

Any ideas? Thanks for your time.

Eric

Answer (score 1):

I just posted a solution to StackOverflow that you might find helpful.
Our certificates are in .cer format and work fine

[Programmatically Install Certificate into Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435000/programmatically-install-certificate-into-mozilla/31568547#31568547)