# How to install certificates to Firefox (Fiddler)?

Tags: c#, fiddler

I use Fiddler dll to install Fiddler certificates:

```
   public static bool InstallCertificate()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(certmakerBcCert))
        {
            FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.key", certmakerBcKey);
            FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", certmakerBcCert);
        }

        if (!CertMaker.rootCertExists())
        {
            //CLog.writeNoLogInDB("Creating SSL certificate");
            if (!CertMaker.createRootCert())
                return false;

            if (!CertMaker.trustRootCert())
                return false;

            certmakerBcCert = FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.cert", null);
            certmakerBcKey = FiddlerApplication.Prefs.GetStringPref("fiddler.certmaker.bc.key", null);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

However, they don't install into firefox. Every browsers work fine except Firefox. Is there a way to install them into Firefox also **through code?**

Thanks!!

**Note:** I already have a program to install a certificate in Firefox, but I need them firstto be generated...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically Install Certificate into Mozilla](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435000/programmatically-install-certificate-into-mozilla)

Comment: nop I added in description

Comment: what do you mean generated?

Comment: If I have a file that is a certificate, I have a program to install it in FF

Comment: are you asking how to get the fiddler cert?

Comment: well if I can programatically, because so far I generate it through Fiddler application :( sorry for delay

Comment: Oh you want to get the fiddler cert programmatically! Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: well np, maybe I can explain it differently if it's unclear in my description? Feel free to edit it, if you did misunderstood my problem, others will

Comment: `CertMaker` has a method that allows you to export the .CER file, you can pass that file into the tool you have that installs the certificate in Firefox.

Comment: @EricLaw this would exactly be what I needed. I searched it for a while of Fiddler site and on forums, didn't come accross it. Would you know about it?

Comment: You should use appropriate error checking but here's the general idea: `File.WriteAllBytes("whatever.cer", CertMaker.GetRootCertificate().Export(X509ContentType.Cert));`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can generate and tell fiddler to use it. I would guess that if it doesn't exist, fiddler creates one at install time [this here implies there is a set location](https://www.fiddlerbook.com/fiddler/help/httpsclientcerts.asp)

Comment: thanks ! will work on that and post again with my results. May take little time

Comment: The link you've cited concerns *client* certificates, so no, it's not related to the issue at hand. To export the *Fiddler root* certificate, you must do so in another way.