# how to Add Certificate programmatically into Firefox version 59, Cannot find cert9.db in firefox folder

Tags: ssl, firefox, certificate, store, certutil

Good day.

I have our own Certificate Authority (CA) that we need to add to Mozilla Firefox Browser, as ive researches that Firefox has its own certificate management.

But we need to add it programmatically, as we have our own application that automatically adds our certificates to IE, Edge and Chrome for our clients.

I have used Firefox version 59. Since i don't have experience on creating a code on doing this, i looked around and came across a solution. but it didn't work with either our .cer or pem certificates.

https://github.com/christian-korneck/firefox_add-certs
 - i think this will only work with Firefox 39.

I found another article, which has several solutions. and towards the end someone says from Firefox 58, it only uses cert9.db

[Programmatically Install Certificate into Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435000/programmatically-install-certificate-into-mozilla)

But i cannot find any cert8.db or cert9.db on the firefox folders. Even if i add my certificate manually. there is no profile folder generated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCh03.png)

I am not stuck in this problem. 
I hope anyone can give me a working code solution for windows ( either through a command script or a powershell script), that i can add our certificate to Firefox 59 certificate store.

Thanks for your help and support, 
Rommel

Comment: Something like this, for Firefox 85, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435000/programmatically-install-certificate-into-mozilla/66223301#66223301

Answer (score 0):

This may be done (I did it some years ago for a project in a previous job) with
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/NSS/tools/NSS_Tools_certutil
(not up to date doc, as it still say cert8.db)

But ...

- Firefox doesn't provide certutil.exe (I checked on my Windows 10,
  there is one provided, but I don't know if it may be used.  On a
  Windows 7 it wasn't by default)
- For a multi user PC, you'll have to
  browser ALL profiles to add your certificate for each user.
- Since FF
  58, they use a new version I saw (previously it was in a cert8.db
  file, now it seems to be in cert9.db file in the user Profile)
- I found this about upgrade to cert9.db https://wiki.mozilla.org/NSS_Shared_DB#The_proposal

Some doc about playing with certX.db

- https://wiki.mozilla.org/NSS_Shared_DB_Howto
- a git which provided an
  old certutil.exe with an interesting issue
  https://github.com/christian-korneck/firefox_add-certs/issues/10

Arfy

Comment: Something like you mention, for Firefox 85, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435000/programmatically-install-certificate-into-mozilla/66223301#66223301