# Can’t use Mozilla’s cert9.db with certutil.exe

Tags: certificate, nss, certutil

The following command: `certutil.exe -L -d “C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\1bku2z91.default-1633392324717\”`
returns this error message: `certutil.exe: function failed: SEC_ERROR_LEGACY_DATABASE: The certificate/key database is in an old, unsupported format.`

I tried with and without quotes, changed backslash to forward slash. I found comments that the destination folder has to include `secmod.db`, which my folder does not but I think this applied to `cert8.db`, not `cert9.db`. I am passing the right folder as per `about:support` lookup. My Firefox version is `66.0.3`

Answer (score 5):

you need to add "sql:" before the location of the folder to specify that is a sqlite db that you are trying to read so it would be:

```
certutil.exe -L -d sql:“C:\Users\Home\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\1bku2z91.default-1633392324717\”
```