# How do I programatticaly import a client certificate for use in Firefox on CentOS 7

Tags: docker, firefox, centos7, client-certificates, pfx

I'm doing automated testing from a CentOS 7 docker container using a headless Firefox browser and need to authenticate to the website I am testing.  I have a .pfx client certificate and password, which I can successfully import/authenticate from a Windows Firefox UI but need to now duplicate in the CentOS docker container.

Do I need to convert the .pfx file and, if so, how do I do so programmatically so that I am not prompted for the password?

Where do I need to place the cert on the CentOS container so that Firefox can access it?

Any other additional steps in order for Firefox to automatically authenticate using the certs I have provided?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically Install Certificate into Mozilla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435000/programmatically-install-certificate-into-mozilla)

Comment: Yes, that is similar to what I ended up doing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve my issues by simply copying a Firefox profile, after adding the cert via the GUI and selecting auto select cert.