# Firefox without SSL certificates

Tags: ssl, firefox, ssl-certificate

I am trying to build a solution for deployment to a manufacturing test environment where security is not a concern. I have an embedded system under test that offers up a web interface. This web interface uses a self-signed certificate and that's not going to change.

I would like to be able to connect to this device, and using any kind of one-off certificate accepting process is not a viable solution, since every device under test would require a separate certificate based on it having a different MAC address.

My question is, can I run Firefox with either command line arguments or some kind of configuration that tells it to completely ignore certificates? Alternatively, is there a way I can create a certificate exemption that ignores the MAC address of the device and says to accept the certificates from ANY device at a specific IP address? Alternatively, is there another browser I can use that might not care about certificates?

Comment: Why not just use plain HTTP (i.e. no SSL) if you want to avoid certificates? Also, no browser cares about MAC addresses. It is instead relevant that a) the certificate is issued by a trusted CA, b) the subject/SAN of the certificates matches the name in the URL and c) the certificate is still valid (not expired or revoked).

Comment: Just trusting the self-signed certificate should also do it. That can be a one off, but I'm pretty sure you can also insert it into the certificate store using some call or other. See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1435000/589259) for more info.